# Make wordpress admin menu item only for admin users

Tags: php, html, wordpress

Im adding a sub-menu under WordPress admin menu for my plugin

```
add_submenu_page(
        'demo',       // parent slug
        'Demo Settings',    // page title
        'Demo Settings',             // menu title
        'manage_options',           // capability
        'demo_settings',      // slug
        'show_demo_settings' // callback
    );
```

and this is adding a menu item which is available for all users, all level of users, I want to make it visible for only administrators, searched quite a bit but not found any solution in their documentation.

any one worked on this kind of problem?

Comment: I dont understand why people simply downvote/upvote, I assume they do it when they dont know what to answer, please explain so others can learn form it, Down Voters!

Answer (score 2):

roles is the trick,
set the appropriate capability for the level of users you want to show the menu items

https://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities

so a menu that need to be displayed to editors would have capability "edit_pages"

```
add_submenu_page(
        'demo',       // parent slug
        'Demo Settings',    // page title
        'Demo Settings',             // menu title
        'edit_pages',           // capability
        'demo_settings',      // slug
        'show_demo_settings' // callback
    );
```

the menu required for only admins would be with this capability "manage_options"

```
add_submenu_page(
        'demo',       // parent slug
        'Demo Settings',    // page title
        'Demo Settings',             // menu title
        'manage_options',           // capability
        'demo_settings',      // slug
        'show_demo_settings' // callback
    );
```

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/nav-menu-roles/

This plugin lets you hide custom menu items based on user roles. So if you have a link in the menu that you only want to show to logged in users, certain types of users, or even only to logged out users, this plugin is for you.

Comment: I used this plugin @randy, Im trying to do it with code so my plugin works with out this plugin